# Parameters inside JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

I know this is probably explained somewhere, but I haven't actually found what I'm looking for. I'm developing an android app for searching movies, using the movie database api. I'm also using okhttp, and the default json (org.json). I can't quite figure it out on how to extract the parameters that I want in the json that is returned to me by the api.

The return is the following

```
{
    "total_results": x,
    "results": [
    {
      "popularity": xxxx,
      "id": xxxx,
      "title": "xxxx",
      "vote_average": 8,
      "overview": "xxxx",
    },
    {
      "popularity": xxxx,
      "id": xxxx,
      "title": "xxxx",
      "vote_average": 8,
      "overview": "xxxx",
    }]
}
```

I would like to keep the parameters above. I understand how to get "total_results",

```
@Override
public void run() {
int j=0;
     try {
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);

          j = json.getInt("total_results");
     } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
     mTextViewResult.setText("Results: " + j);
}
```

but how can I get the parameters inside "results"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use getJsonArray():

```
try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);

        j = json.getInt("total_results");
        JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i=0; i<results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject thisResult = results.getJSONObject(i);
            String thisTitle = thisResult.getString("title");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```